# Check if an calendar event is going on

Tags: android, calendar

I need to check if there is currently an calendar event that is "busy".

```
String[] projection = new String[] { BaseColumns._ID};
String selection = CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " <= ? AND "
        + CalendarContract.Events.DTEND + ">= ? AND "
        + CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY + "=="
        + CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY;

Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        selection,
        new String[] {String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()),
        String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())},
        null);
```

This code works fine, but not for recurring events.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is switch the table you read from, [see here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).

`CalendarContract.Instances` should provide all the events including recurring ones

> This table holds the start and end time for each occurrence of an event. Each row in this table represents a single event occurrence. For one-time events there is a 1:1 mapping of instances to events. For recurring events, multiple rows are automatically generated that correspond to multiple occurrences of that event.

Comment: Thats it. Thanks.